# How to trigger a selectionChange event only when users change the selection of a combobox in C# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, selectionchanged

I would like to know how to trigger the selectionChange event of a combobox only when the user himself change the selection of the list. (Avoid other cases) I found a solution here but I have some errors. Could you help me?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx

I added System.Windows.Forms in my .cs file and it says there is an ambiguity beetween 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox' and 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' with the first line of the code below.

I dont know how to cast my sender into a comboBox.

```
ComboBox senderComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

        if (senderComboBox.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            //code here
        }
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference `WinForms ComboBox` and not `WPF ComboBox`. You can listen to `SelectionChanged` event of the control to know when user changes the selection.

A sample code from [dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/combobox-wpf)

XAML

```
<ComboBox
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="10,10,0,0"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="120"
    Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded"
    SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

CS File

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... Get the ComboBox.
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

    // ... Set SelectedItem as Window Title.
    string value = comboBox.SelectedItem as string;
    this.Title = "Selected: " + value;
}
```

Comment: My interpretation of the question is that he wants to know explicitly when a user has changed the value - as opposed to when it has been changed programmatically at runtime.

Comment: @AdrianK The issue he is raising is due to the fact that he referenced a ComboBox from Winforms and not WPF. If the user explicitly changed the value then that should trigger an event for SelectionChanged. It doesn't matter if it's changed at programatically runtime or user did it.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of approach worked for me - [XAML ComboBox SelectionChanged Fires OnLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762042/xaml-combobox-selectionchanged-fires-onload)

Basically only wire-up the ComboBox_SelectionChanged event after the form has loaded - this will get you around the programmatic change that will fire onload.  Beyond that I'm not sure.  It might be that you need to use a different event, but I haven't looked into this.